# C# Caerle encima a un string con otro

Tags: c#

resulta que tengo una cadena de texto a la cual me gustaría caerle encima con otra cadena de texto. Existe algún método de la clase String que pueda aplicar para hacer eso ? Gracias

Ejemplo:

```
string nombre = "          "; //10 caracteres
string nombreInsertar = "Steven" //6 caracteres

resultado = "Steven    " //se mantienen los 10 caracteres de la variable //nombre solo inserto los 6 caracteres de la segunda variable a partir de la posición 0.
```

Agradezco la ayuda, Saludos.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "caerle encima"?

Answer (score 3):

Usa la interpolación de cadenas:

```
var nombre = "Steven";
var resultado1 = $"{nombre,  10}"; // el resultado es "    Steven"
var resultado2 = $"{nombre, -10}"; // el resultado es "Steven    ";
```

Si quieres que sea "dinámico", puedes crear un método de extensión:

```
public static class FuncionesCadenas
{
    public string CaeEncimaDe(this string cadena1, string cadena2)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cadena1) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cadena2)))
            return string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cadena1))
            return cadena2;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cadena2) || cadena2.Length <= cadena1.Length)
            return cadena1;

       return $"{cadena1}{cadena2.Substring(cadena1.Length, cadena2.Length - cadena1.Length)}";
    }
}
```

Y lo usas:

```
var espacio = "    "
var nombreInsertar = "Steven"
string resultado = nombreInsertar.CaeEncimaDe(espacio);
// resultado: "Steven    "
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Toma solo la parte del segundo string que te interesa con el método `Substring`, el primer parámetro que recibe le indica a partir de que posición leer.  Luego simplemente combinas ambos.

```
var resultado = nombreInsertar + nombre.Substring(nombreInsertar.Length);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que planteas puedes usar

```
public static void Main()
{
    string nombreInsertar = "Steven";
    string resultado = string.Format("{0, -10}", nombreInsertar);
    //string resultado = nombreInsertar.PadRight(10);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", resultado);
}
```

Hay dos alternativas

- `{0, -10}` con el `string.Format()`
- PadRight(10)

Comment: Muchas gracias!